# Moving content up in divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to check all the divs in a section and trying to make sure that the content in the section is in the top-most div.

For example if I have Div1 and Div2, and Div1 is empty but Div2 has an image, then the image in Div2 will be moved up to Div1.

I'm trying to do this using a for loop in javascript, but it isn't working.

Javascript:

```
function checky() {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('container').childNodes;
    for (var i = 1; i < wrapper.length; i++) {
        if (wrapper[i].innerHTML <= 10 && i>1) {
            if (wrapper[i-1].innerHTML <= 10) {
                //move the stuff
            }
        }
    }
};
var okie = checky();
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
...
</div>
```

Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Can you give a more broader description, because ideally you can just delete the div and rename the others as it is empty anyways.

Comment: If they are empty...why are they there in the first place and what code empties them?

Comment: I want to avoid deleting the empty divs, because they have unique styling/placement. I just want to move up the content, if that makes sense. So if Div1, Div2, Div3, and Div4 is empty but Div5 does have an image in it, I want to just move up the Image to Div 1 without deleting any divs. The divs are boxes, and you can add an image to these boxes or delete images from these boxes. SO if you delet an image from div2, the image from div3 and div4 etc will move up.